# NTLDR is missing while installing Ubunttu

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I downloaded *ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386* and I burned it on a USB drive. When I tried to install ubuntu from the USB on a PC (previously having Windows-XP), I got an error :

```
NTLDR is missing
Press any key to reboot
```

What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

try using Unetbootin, it usually solves problems with burning linux bootable USB under windows if that`s your situation.

also if your BIOS supports force booting from your USB, try booting that way instead of configuring boot order.